# Django admin: La verificación CSRF falló. Solicitud anulada

Tags: python, django, web, tokens, python-requests

Saludos amigos Developers, de manera formal quiero consultarles sobre un error que surge al estar utilizando el `admin` de `django`. Básicamente agregué un modelo en `models.py`, el archivo luce así:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Y en la vista aun no tengo nada, luce así:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
```

Entonces, una vez estoy dentro del admin y agrego datos a mis campos de "`Products`" (`name, description, category, price`), procedo a hacer clic en "`Save`" e inmediatamente me arroja el siguiente error:

> *CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. You are seeing this message
>   because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This
>   cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser
>   is not being hijacked by third parties. If you have configured your
>   browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this
>   site, or for 'same-origin' requests.*

He leído varios foros pero la solución que aplican no me ha servido, imagino que es por la leve diferencia de que en la mayoría de casos es problema con una "`view`", pero en mi caso es directamente con el admin (pienso que no debería tener este error).

**Nota:** Como complemento les cuento que el proyecto lo estoy trabajando sobre `C9`, para los que no conocen es una plataforma que permite trabajar nuestros proyectos online. Mas info => [c9.io](http://c9.io)

Comment: Hola Hernan, ¿como has definido tu archivo admin.py?, ¿puedes mostrar su contenido?

Comment: Buenas puede ser de muchas cosas, si no tienes template definida, intenta borrar el render del template "from django.shortcuts import render"  y mostrar aquí el contenido del archivo admin.py, tienes algún html definido?

Comment: Saludos amigos, gracias por las respuestas, en cuanto a lo que menciona César, a continuación comparto el admin.py:                                                     
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Product


    #admin.site.register(Product)
    @admin.register(Product)
    class AdminProduct(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'category', 'description', 'price',)
    list_filter = ('category',)

Comment: En cuanto al comentario de Yoel, ya he avanzado en el proyecto y ya tengo definida una vista llamada **"index.html"**, te comparto el código aquí: (https://paste.ofcode.org/35u7MdDHMLZdwVnC42ZfizT)

Comment: Suponiendo esto solo te suceda en produccion y no en un ambiente local:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095989/django-csrf-verification-failed-for-admin-panel

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: fredyfx la verdad no Bro, seguí trabajando normal mi proyecto omitiendo el error y al final ejecuté y creo los seres Celestiales de la Programación vinieron en mi ayuda por que funcionó! (Jajajajaja). Saludos.

Comment: Que direccion estás usando para acceder al admin desde el navegador, que direccion colocaste en python manage.py runserver y cual direccion tienes permitida en settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: esto me esta sucediendo también desde hace un año con la versión 2 de Django en modo de desarrollo. Probé mucho tiempo con agregar CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True al settings.py y me solucionó hasta que hace poco me volvió a suceder, le quite esta linea de código y funcionó perfectamente. Decir que CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE por defecto debe venir en True, pero en una versión lo dejaron False y en la siguiente ya salió bien. Como último creo que se trata más de un problema de cookies. Lo bueno es que en producción no me ha sucedido.

Answer (score 1):

Ese error que comentas no es muy común que se presente pero puedo recomendarte que te asegures de haber hecho esto.

Crear tu app

```sh
 python manage.py startapp demo
```

Lo cual genera una estructura similar a esto:
asegurate de agregar esta nueva app en tu settings

```
--demo
---- __init__.py
---- models.py
---- admin.py
```

model.py

```py
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

admin.py

```py
@admin.register(Product)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = (
        'name', 'description', 'category', 'price',)
```

No te olvides generar la migración ejecutarlo.

Luego ejecuta el proyecto y debería funcionar.

**---- Dato extra**
*El error de CSRF se da cuando usas formulario en html de tu aplicación que se conecta a tus url, bajo el concepto que llama django MVT model view template.*  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 1):

Has verificado que  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' esté en la lista MIDDLEWARE en tus ajustes de Django (settings.py)?

Porque lo primero que hay que tener en cuenta es que es un error en la verificación CSRF

Si es así, prueba a incluir el contexto 'django.template.context_processors.csrf' en la configuración del motor de plantillas si no lo está ya:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ...
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                # ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Y también debes asegurarte de que tu navegador acepta cookies.